# Replacing Apache instance with Tomcat 6

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat6

I'm on a Linux machine and am trying to replace an Apache2 instance with a Tomcat 6 instance. I shut down the Apache instance by running a kill on the appropriate pid, but when I try to access any pages, I get an error 504 instead of 404. Additionally, when I run the Tomcat 6 instance, I still get the error 504. Requests to port 80 get returned much faster than requests to port 8080. Any idea what I can do to get Tomcat 6 up and running?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Apache, Tomcat configuration files?

Comment: The Tomcat configuration file is the default. The regular Apache instance shouldn't be running.

Comment: Which distro are you running? Why not stop Apache in standard way via init script instead of `kill pid`? Are you sure you kill the parent process? `lsof -i :80` or `netstat -natp | grep :80`?

Comment: Both of those return nothing.

Comment: `ps -ef | egrep 'apache|httpd'`? Post the Apache configuration file?

Comment: The distro is red hat. I can't post the httpd.conf contents, but I checked the error and access logs, and nothing is getting recorded since I killed the process. That line returns the command itself and nothing else.

Comment: If so, nobody can help.

Comment: Is there something specific you're looking for?

Comment: I suspect that there is a running Apache instance which forwards request to the backend. But the backend cannot response, so you get the 504 gateway timeout error.

Comment: ps aux | grep apache shows nothing. The only other process that looks like it can work with the connection is dhclient. That can't be causing the problem, can it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The firewall was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you might try `lsof -p 33333 | grep TCP` where 33333 is your tomcat's pid, you could then see where connections are being made. With the 504 on 8080 AND 80, my first guess would be that you have a loop, and that you forward request from one to another or on the same one... that could explain the timeouts, but we don't have much to work on with what you give us.

Comment: That returns: TCP *:webcache (LISTEN), TCP *:8009 (LISTEN),  TCP localhost.localdomain:8005 (LISTEN)